# MySQL join : unknown column in field list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to do simple MySQL joins?

I have 2 tables which look like this:

```
companies
   id | name | type_id 

types
   id | type
```

Now all I want to do is get an array which looks something like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => business name
        [type] => type name
    )

)
```

I have tried this in mysql:

```
SELECT 
`companies.id`,`companies.name`,`types.type`

FROM `companies`

RIGHT JOIN `types` ON  `companies.type_id` = `types.id`
```

but I get this error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'companies.id' in 'field list'

Do I have the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5):

Problem is the way you escaping the column like below which is taking the entire string as column name and thus the error

```
`companies.id`
```

It rather should be below, means you need to escape the table name and column name separately

```
`companies`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put backticks around the qualified column names.  So, MySQL is looking for a column name called "companies.id" (with a period in the name), not the "id" column in "companies".

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, t.type
FROM types t LEFT JOIN
     companies c
     ON c.type_id = t.id;
```

Your query (with the column names fixed) would keep all rows in `types` even when there is no matching company.  The above does the same thing.  If you really want all companies, then make that the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.  If the types always match, then use `INNER JOIN`.

Notes:

- I'm not sure why you are using an outer join.  But, `LEFT JOIN` is preferable to `RIGHT JOIN` because the semantics are simpler:  keep everything in the first table plus matching columns in the rest.
- Table aliases make the query easier to read and to write.
- There is no need to escape the column or table names.  Simpler to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
`companies.id`,`companies.name`,`types.type`

FROM `companies`

JOIN `types` ON  where `companies.type_id` = `types.id`
```